# Cover or Do Away with the Brick Ledge on Foundation Wall

Tags: foundation, brick

We have a brick veneer on the front face of the foundation wall that goes down about 4 bricks in depth on that foundation by way of a brick ledge, making that foundation top side smaller than the rest of the other foundation walls.

That side's sill plate is thus only a 2x4, unlike the rest, which are 2x8. We are rebuilding on that foundation, and need to get that front to have a uniform sized sill plate. What would be a structurally sound approach to covering that brick ledge so that we can get a 2x8 sill plate on top?

Do we need to remove the bricks, then add cement, or can we pour over & cover the brick flush? Is that structurally sound? I've searched but couldn't readily find a similar situation. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: This would be easier to answer with a picture.  It sounds like the brick is decorative, in which case it probably was not installed in a way that would make it trustworthy for structural support.  You want a proper foundation, likely with a footing rather than tying into the old foundation.  The old foundation was designed to support just the original load.  Work of this type needs to be designed by an engineer or architect, and approved.  Your situation may be covered by existing standards, in which case, your builder could follow those standards.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234. Our foundation is there and solid/proper. The brick ledge is exactly like this right side picture. We want to make that lege solid since we no longer use the brick veneer. One way is to fill the legde with concrete, but how to best do it; or other options that are easier but stucturally sound.  https://www.finehomebuilding.com/app/uploads/cms/uploadedimages/images/homebuilding/qa/hb115qa01-02_lg.jpg